# How to add words to vim coloring in C/C++ mode?

Tags: vim

I notice that in C/C++ mode, comments such as `TODO` `XXX` and `FIXME` get special color marking.

*How can I add the word `HACK` to this list of words to be marked in the same way?*

I tried adding the following to my `~/.vimrc`, but it didn't work:

```
syn keyword cTodo   contained TODO FIXME XXX HACK
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I would advise against directly modifying the original syntax file; you then have to maintain your version whenever the original changes (e.g. after a Vim upgrade). For these small syntax enhancements, the place is in the `~/.vim/after/syntax/c.vim` file, which is sourced *after* the original syntax. The line would be

```
syn keyword cTodo   contained HACK
```

Comment: +1 excellent - thx for the tip - I was wondering if there was a better alternative than the always brittle `copy-and-paste` method - will try it out!  Tried it: WORKS GREAT - ty.

Answer (score 4):

You need to modify the syntax file. Typically, it is in `/usr/share/vim/vim72/syntax`, and the file you want is `c.vim` and `cpp.vim`. You will see a line `syn keyword cTodo contained` followed by a list of words that are considered under the Todo label for coloring. You can add your word there, or make your own keyword, but adding your own keyword would mean adding your keyword to the coloring file as well.

For user only changes, make a directory `~/.vim/syntax`. Copy the c.vim and cpp.vim files there, and edit as necessary.

Second edit: Decided to look further, and it appears you can just add to a current syntax file, but I haven't tried it. Add your one line you added to your .vimrc to a file in `~/.vim/after/syntax`

Comment: thx - how do I make changes so it applies to me only?  I tried adding something to my ~/.vimrc but that didn't work (look at edited OP).